# Google Places Auto-Complete

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

The input box is initialized properly but it is not generating any suggestions. Can any one point out what I am doing wrong? [Here](http://pastebin.com/eFyuUMEj) is the code.

**Update**

I have investigated the issue. The problem is in the line:

```
types: ['(cities)', '(regions)']
```

when I specify only one type `types: ['(cities)']` no matter `region or cities` it works. But two types are not working together. Although the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#AutocompleteOptions) clearly says that `types` are Array of strings and valid values are `'establishment', 'geocode', '(regions)' and '(cities)'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete):

> *"types, which can either specify one of two explicit types or one of two type collections."*

This means that the `types` array only supports one parameter.

If you think it would be a useful feature to support more than one parameter or a mixture of explicit types and collections, please file a [Places API - Feature Request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Comment: But it was working few days earlier and then suddenly stopped working, what's the reason for that?

Comment: We were not enforcing this restriction until recently, but to allow for new features we had to start enforcing.

Comment: Here's a use: either searching by zip code AND searching by address.

Answer (score 2):

As Chris mentioned, there is currently no way to get results for multiple place types. 
However, you can call the API twice with different place types and populate a map (or whatever you're building) with both types. For example:

```
var request1 = {
  location: event.latLng,
  radius: 8047,
  types: ['cafe'],
};
var request2 = {
  location: event.latLng,
  radius: 8047,
  types: ['library'],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no results of type (cities)'  or '(regions)'.  If I change the types array to ['establishment'], I get results.

[Working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_autocompleteA.html)

If you use only one type, it works:

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_autocompleteB.html)

Comment: Bounds are just an initial boundary to start looking for, this does not restrict the results to just those bounds unless you explicitly define.

Comment: the issue is if you define two groups in types, the auto-complete never generate suggestions.

Comment: two groups were working few days ago. I think the library is updated and there is a bug.

Comment: I just found the same thing.  Probably should report the problem in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/)

Comment: I did, please star there http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4538