# Google Places API: How to use multiple types?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I need a POI API that returns ratings, photos, opening/closing times, etc and I thought Google Places API seemed to do what I want, but I am having some trouble with filtering: I want to use the autocomplete feature with multiple types for filtering.

Here is what I have:

```
var map;
var selectAttractionAutocomplete;
var selectCityAutocompleteOptions = {
    types: ['(cities)']
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316),
    zoom: 15
});

var inputsearchedCity = document.getElementById('input-searched-city');
selectCityAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputsearchedCity, selectCityAutocompleteOptions);
selectCityAutocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

google.maps.event.addListener(selectCityAutocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    console.log(selectCityAutocomplete.getPlace());
});
```

How can I use multiple types?

I have tried pipes, commas, brackets... nothing works:

```
var selectCityAutocompleteOptions = {
    types: ['cities|point_of_interest']
};
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#AutocompleteOptions) _"In general only a single type is allowed. The exception is that you can safely mix the 'geocode' and 'establishment' types, but note that this will have the same effect as specifying no types."_

Comment: Although given it should accept an array of strings, to specify that you would need to do it like `types: ['cities', 'point_of_interest']`

Comment: I've tried commas, and 'cities' on its own doesn't work. 'cities' needs to be '(cities)'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types), `point_of_interest`is of type 2, which are not supported in the types filter of a place search, or in the types property when adding a place.

Comment: So, how to fetch multiples types now?

Answer (score 12):

If your are using in a query string, use the | separator. Remember that only 'geocode|establishment' is currently valid as a collection type, which is the same than not specifying any combined type.

See:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types

> You may restrict results from a Place Autocomplete request to be of a certain type by passing a types parameter. The parameter specifies a type or a type collection, as listed in the supported types below. If nothing is specified, all types are returned. In general only a single type is allowed. The exception is that you can safely mix the geocode and establishment types, but note that this will have the same effect as specifying no types.

Comment: This is the answer!

Answer (score 1):

This question is partly answered in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233196/google-places-auto-complete/58158599#58158599).

First, the place type of "cities" it not supported. You can find a list of supported place types [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types).

There is no way to use multiple types at once. However, you can call the API twice in order to get similar results. For example:

```
var selectCityAutocompleteOptions1 = {
  types: ['zoo']
};
var selectCityAutocompleteOptions2 = {
  types: ['museum']
};
```

Based off of your description, though, it sounds like you want all points of interest results, without filtering by type. In that case you might want to use a [Find Place Requests Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#FindPlaceRequests) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this recently. Answer is here [Google Places Auto-Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233196/google-places-auto-complete)

> types, which can either specify **one of two explicit types** *or* **one of two type collections**.

Answer (score -6):

```
var request = {
    bounds: map.getBounds(),
    types: ['bar','park']
      //keyword: 'best view'
  };
```

Comment: Please explain how your contribution answers the question.