# Google places: Use multiple types

Tags: javascript, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This question is an update to some outdated questions:

- [Google Places Auto-Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233196/google-places-auto-complete)
- [Google Places API: How to use multiple types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625112/google-places-api-how-to-use-multiple-types?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

Because I need a way to get all near **restaurants**, **stores**, and **churches** I thought Google Places API seemed to do what I want, but I am having some trouble with filtering: I want to search for multiple **places-types** in one request.

```
let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
url += "location=" + 79.999 + "," + 8.999
url += "radius=" + 2000
url += "type=" + mytype// ??
url += "key=" + mykey
```

This is what my url should look like. But I got trouble setting multiple types like:

Setting `mytype` to maybe "restaurant" is working quite fine.

Setting `mytype` to "restaurant,store,church" is not working.

Setting `mytype` to "[restaurant,store,church]" is also not working.

---

I know that the feature searching for **multiple place types** was disabled by Google a long time ago. But using the javascript API works absolutely fine with multiple types so the URL request probably should also work this way.

Answer (score 1):

Seperating the types with `"|"` is doing the job.

```
let mytype = "restaurant|food|store"
let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
url += "location=" + 79.999 + "," + 8.999
url += "radius=" + 2000
url += "type=" + mytype// ??
url += "key=" + mykey
```

Volià, hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple types is not possible in Google Places

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Go through the above link:

Under Nearby Search requests section you will find the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Links are good for providing supporting documentation for the answer. But please include the actual answer in any answers.